# combining comparisons operators

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please advise how to change the following code to extract also records with [execution_status] like 'failure' and at the same time [has_messages] like '0'. I'm trying different ways and all the time results include has_messages both '0' and '1' :(. Thanks a lot!!

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT [id]
            ,[type]
            ,[created]
            ,dateadd(s, created/1000, '19700101')as date_created
            ,[state]
            ,[execution_status]
            ,[has_messages]
      FROM [databasename].[tablename] 
      WHERE type like 'AccessRequest' 
        AND not state like 'Initialize') as jaro 
WHERE date_created between '2016-12-01' and '2016-12-31'
ORDER by date_created
```

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Why do you use `LIKE`? Doesn't `=` work for you?

Comment: For records with `execution_status = 'failure' and has_messages = 0` you don't care what type and state they have, correct?

Comment: BTW: be aware that `date_created` has a time part. Your `BETWEEN` clause reads like `date_created between '2016-12-01 00:00:00' and '2016-12-31 00:00:00'`, i.e. excluding the last day except for its first second.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a bunch of suggestions.  First, I would modify the table to have a computed column for the date:

```
alter table tablename add date_created as (dateadd(second, created/1000, '19700101'));
```

This would allow you to add an index on to the column which could speed the query.  Then, you should fix your date comparisons (read Aaron Bertrand's excellent explanation [What do BETWEEN and the Devil Have In Common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)):

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where (date_created >= '2016-12-01' and date_created < '2017-01-01') and
      ((type like 'AccessRequest' AND state not like 'Initialize') or
       (execution_status like 'failure' and has_messages like '0')
      )
```

Additional comments:

- Do not use like for numeric values.  If `has_messages` is numeric, simply use `=`.
- Although you *can* use `like` for your string comparisons, many people would agree that `=` is clearer in intent.
- This query will still get values where `has_message` is not `0`, because these rows satisfy the original condition.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT
               id
              ,type
              ,created
              ,dateadd(s, created/1000, '19700101') AS date_created
              ,state
              ,execution_status
              ,has_messages
        FROM databasename.tablename 
       WHERE (type = 'AccessRequest' 
         AND state != 'Initialize')
          OR (execution_status = 'failure' 
         AND has_messages = 0)
     ) AS jaro
WHERE date_created >= '2016-12-01' <= '2016-12-31'
ORDER BY date_created
```

Comment: Where you close the subquery? why repeat the date condition?

Comment: sorry missed your subquery, let me make a correction

Comment: Dont worry, isnt mine. Now you need add another parenthesis to cover the `OR` conditions